# entity framework code first soft delete

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, soft-delete

I have Entities with field DeletedAt. Those entities implement ISoftDelete. 
What i want is to automatically ignore all rows that have value on DeletedAt. Is it possible?

one thought was discriminator, but this is more for inheritance.

it would be really nice if there were that feature in DbModelBuilder like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ISoftDelete>().Where(x => x.DeletedAt == null)
```

Comment: Could you use a repository pattern and build this into a common `GetAll()` method?

Comment: I would like that if I use collection properties, then I would get also all rows that are not deleted.

Comment: What's your issue with the discriminator method you outline? It's what I currently use and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Create Another Extender and inside it put

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ISoftDelete>().Where(x => x.DeletedAt == null)
```

and it should return data as queryable.